Lee Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Problem 9-2
I'm trying to do problem 9-2 from John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
The problem is: Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $S \subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold, and $V$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ that is tangent to $S$.
(a). Show that for any integral curve $\gamma$ of $V$ such that $\gamma(t_0) \in S$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\gamma \left(\left(t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon\right)\right) \subseteq S$.
(b). Now assume $S$ is properly embedded. Show that every integral curve that intersects $S$ is contained in $S$.
(c). Give a counterexample to (b) if $S$ is not closed.
My approach to (a):
Let $\gamma : J \rightarrow M$ be an integral curve such that $q = \gamma(t_0) \in S$. Since $S$ is a smooth (immersed) submanifold of $X$, the restriction $V |_S$ is a smooth vector field on $S$ which is $\iota-$related to $V$ where $\iota : S \rightarrow M$ is the inclusion map.
By Proposition 9.2, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and a smooth curve $\gamma_S : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow S$ such that $\gamma_S$ is an integral curve starting at $q$.
Then, by Proposition 9.6 (Naturality of Integral curves), $V$ and $V|_S$ being $\iota-$related means $\iota\left(\gamma_S\right) = \gamma_S$ is an integral curve in $M$. But due to the uniqueness of integral curves, it must be the case that $\gamma_S(t) = \gamma(t)$ for $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \cap J$. Therefore, for $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \cap J$(?), we have $\gamma(t) \in S$ i.e. $\gamma \left((t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)\right) \subseteq S$.
Does this look right?
I'm not sure how to approach (b). Any hints/advice would be appreciated.
For (c), I know an embedded submanifold is properly embedded iff it is closed. So, for my counterexample, I'm thinking of the embedding $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n$ whose image is $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus {N}$ where $N$ is the north pole.  Then, any integral curve passing through the north pole is  not contained in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I'm not sure if this is valid.

(a)
Your solution looks correct.
(b)
By proposition 5.5, we know $S$ is closed in $M$.
Since $\gamma$ is a continuous map, the preimage $\gamma^{-1}(S)$ is closed in the interval $J = \mathrm{dom}\ \gamma$.
Now, aiming for a contradiction, suppose that $\gamma^{-1}(S)$ is not the whole of $J$.
Using the fact that $\gamma^{-1}(S)$ is closed, you can arrive at a contradiction with part (a).

 Indeed, since $J$ is connected, and $\gamma^{-1}(S)$ is not the whole of $J$, this subset cannot be open too (because a nonempty clopen set corresponds to a disconnection), hence there exists at least one boundary point. But this directly contradicts part (a).

(c)
You can find simpler counterexamples; for instance take $M = \mathbb{R}$, $S = \{x > 0\} \subseteq M$ with the embedded structure (it's an open submanifold), $V = \partial/\partial x$, and $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to M$ defined by $t \mapsto t$.
Then $\gamma$ is an integral curve of $V$ but doesn't lie completely in $S$.
